# Узнать загруженность CPU C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь разбираться с WIN32 API, реши написать что-то на подобии диспетчера задач, но никак не могу понять как узнать нагруженность CPU и его температуру(если это возможно)... 
Понял как узнать архитектуру процессора :

```
LPCSTR getArchitecture()
{
    SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);
    LPCSTR architecture;

    switch (sysInfo.wProcessorArchitecture)
    {
    case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL :
        architecture = "Intel x86";
        break;
    case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64 :
        architecture = "Intel x64";
        break;
    case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 :
        architecture = "AMD x64";
        break;
    case PROCESSOR_AMD_X8664:
        architecture = "AMD x86";
        break;
    default:
        architecture = "Unknow";
        break;  
    }

    return architecture;
}
```

Также понял, как узнать количество ядер процессора:

```
UINT const getCountCernels() 
{
    SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);
    return sysInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
}
```

Хотелось бы получить внятный ответ как можно узнать нагруженность процессора желательно для каждого ядра...

Comment: Возможно NtQuerySystemInformation поможет..

Answer (score 2):

Температуру процессора вряд ли получится узнать без проблем, можно сделать WMI запрос по `MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature`, но это даст только температуру где - то на материнской плате (это может быть далеко от процессора), и то, этого может не быть в материнке вообще. Правильным решением будет писать драйвера. Для этого нужно с помощью инструкции `rdmsr` получить `IA32_THERM_STATUS`, если мы говорим о 32 - bit Intel Architecture, для этого надо будет получить доступ в kernel space (ring 0 права)

Answer (score 2):

Через PDH-функции, в общих чертах, загрузка ядра добывается так:

1. Через PdhOpenQuery создается PDH_HQUERY
2. Через PdhAddEnglishCounter с использованием запроса из п.1 инициализируются счетчики. Путь к счетчику - `"\\Processor(0)\\%% Idle Time"`, где 0 - номер ядра
3. Через PdhCollectQueryData получаются данные
4. PdhGetFormattedCounterValue получает из счетчика значение. Нужно указать тип PDH_FMT_DOUBLE.
5. Из 100 нужно вычесть полученное в п.5 значение
6. ...
7. PROFIT!

Comment: Похоже прийдётся так, нашёл на en so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process

Comment: @nick_n_a я уже не помню, откуда собирал этот алгоритм. enSO был наверняка...